# Octave use of iteration (start:step:end)

Tags: octave

Let's say I have an array `A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]`. I want to iterate through it and do something with each number.

`A(start:step:end)` -> since I want to iterate with step `1` I use `A(1:10)`.

Question here is, how can I use that iteration? In C++ you would do

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    //DO SOMETHING
}
```

I've spent 4 hours searching how to use that iteration. I have not found a single  explanation to such a trivial thing: passing block of code to actually do something with numbers. Don't even know how to use current index (i.e., `i` in C++).

I have my function in Octave `f = @(variable) (...)`, however when I call `f(A(1:10))` it is not really passing each number to the function but rather finishes iteration and then executes function.

I'd expect something like

```
A(1:10) (DO SOMETHING WITH EACH NUMBER)
```

or in my example

```
A(1:10) ( f(INDEX) )
```

but that does not seem to work either.

I know Octave has a built-in for loop but in my case it is too slow.

That was simplified explanation, here is more advanced.
I want to multiply matrix `A` in such way that one matrix starts iteration with `1` and the other one with `2` (e.g., `A(1:end-1).*A(2:end)`) and use each multiplied number in my custom function.

Comment: `A(1:10)` is an array expression; in particular, a vector expression of length 10, which will have shape either 1x10 or 10x1, I can never remember it right. What you want to do seems like what the element-by-element multiplication operator (`.*`) does, so your call to a function would be: `f(A(1:end-1) .* A(2:end))`

Comment: What you're looking for is called vectorization, usually involving [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), but we'd have to know what the function you're using is in order to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An analogue of C++ loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  //DO SOMETHING
}
```

would be

```
for i = 1:10
//DO SOMETHING 
end
```

since Octave indices are 1-based.

There is no `array.forEach(do something)` construction in Octave.

Most of the time, a speed-up is achieved by passing arrays (vectors and matrices) to a function at once, and structuring the function itself so that it can handle an array. How to do the latter depends on what the function is.

Comment: You can do `for i = A ...` and achieve the same results as a `forEach`.

Comment: Slightly different, because `.forEach` gives access to the index as well as array value (might depend on language).

Comment: Huh, I don't remember any implementations that do that right off hand, but yes, you'll only get the value of the element and not the index.